# Rename values in a column using pandas or if/then

Tags: pandas, if-statement

I have the below dataset and would like to rename 1 to Sold, 2 to Sold, and nan to Unsold

DF

| Status |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| nan |

Desired DF

| Status |
| --- |
| Sold |
| Sold |
| Unsold |

I am currently using the replace function but doing each condition separately. Is there a way to do it all at the same time?

`df['Status'] = df['Status'].str.replace['1', 'Sold']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `map` with a dictionary:

```
df['Status'] = df['Status'].map({'1': 'Solde', '2': 'Solde', np.nan: 'Unsold'})
```

*NB. If NaNs are strings:*

```
df['Status'] = df['Status'].map({'1': 'Solde', '2': 'Solde', 'nan': 'Unsold'})
```

Or, if you only have 1/2 -> Sold ; nan -> Unsold:

```
# if real NaN
df['Status'] = np.where(df['Status'].notna(), 'Sold', 'Unsold')

# if string
df['Status'] = np.where(df['Status'].ne('nan'), 'Sold', 'Unsold')
```